# extract youtube links from sidebar on youtube page

Tags: hyperlink, youtube, extract

To save time bookmarking many suggested videos on a youtube page I'd like to save the list of URLs in the sidebar to a file for later.

Extraction tools I've tried for youtube pages exclude suggested (personalized) links to other pages, but I can see them in the code in Firefox by hitting F12, I just can't see how to copy them from there.

I know how to download multiple videos in pytube if that helps (even though here I'm only asking how to save the URLs and not the videos themselves). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to create a bookmarklet or just paste it in the browser console:

```js
javascript: (() => {
  const data = [
    ...document.querySelectorAll('.ytd-watch-next-secondary-results-renderer'),
  ]
    .filter(
      (item) => item.querySelector('h3') && item.querySelector('a#thumbnail')
    )
    .map((item) => ({
      title: item.querySelector('h3').textContent.trim(),
      url: item.querySelector('a#thumbnail').href,
    }))
    .slice(1);

  console.log(data);

  const dataJSON = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);
  const blob = new Blob([dataJSON], { type: 'application/json' });

  const a = document.createElement('a');
  a.download = `${document.title}.json`;
  a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  a.click();
})();
```

Comment: Haven't been able to address this yet but wanted to express thanks before too many months pass:)